# Loading *.mrr files in QGIS or using GDAL

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, multi-resolution-raster

Does anyone know how to load the new proprietary MRR files using QGIS or GDAL?

I tried using Add Vector Layer but QGIS did not recognize this file.

Comment: I believe that the mrr file is a raster format.  So opening as a vector certainly won't work.  I don't think that mrr is yet supported by GDAl and therefore probably isn't supported by QGIS.  I also think the mrr has been around since 2015 so I'm not sure it's that new anymore either.

Comment: Thank you. SAFE (FME Server) has a reader for MRR but not sure if it is free. Is there any tool that is free to read such proprietary formats?

Comment: I would suggest not using the .mrr format any more. It is not supported by GDAL and does not look like support is coming for it anytime soon. Mapinfo usage is lower than ever and I am not sure there is any demand for the .mrr format. The only software that supports MRR is MapInfo and FME. Find a license for either somewhere and convert all your .mrr to something more compatible like .tif, .asc or .flt would be the best option.

https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=today%205-y&q=mapinfo

Comment: GDAL has supported all the functionality that mrr purports to offer (multi-resolutions, sparse-raster, massive data etc) for many years (and for longer than mrr has been around in most cases) but in common formats such as BigTif, ECW and MrSID etc so I suspect that is why the mrr format hasn't really taken off.  If you need this sort of functionality - I'd stick with GDAL as it is not only the de facto tool set for OpenSource GIS but is also the tool set used under the hood by ArcGIS (and possibly others)!

Answer (score 1):

`.mrr` is the MapInfo Multi Resolution Raster and you need MapInfo Pro to be able to create these. It's an additional specific licence over the normal software (usually).

In QGIS you will also have the same issue with there new extended tab format - you need 64bit MapInfo.

See https://www.pitneybowes.com/us/location-intelligence/case-studies/mrr---a-new-raster-file-format.html

It's basically their version of the OGR VRT format.

Answer (score -1):

You may look at following resource, Document also has instructions on how to use MRR format along with QGIS.

https://support.precisely.com/product-downloads/item/mapinfo-mrr-sdk-download/

Answer (score -1):

I have posted an [article](https://robertsgeospatial.com.au/644-2/) to my [website](https://robertsgeospatial.com.au/) on this issue. You can also find a video on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/XNPG1lspvUk).

You can also search for "How to use MRR Rasters in QGIS on Windows using GDAL".

At the present time, the GDAL MRR driver for QGIS is not compatible with the latest versions of QGIS. MapInfo need to update the driver and provide a new download and I hope they will do so soon.

If you want a big MRR raster to try in QGIS go to the MERIT DEM [website](http://hydro.iis.u-tokyo.ac.jp/%7Eyamadai/MERIT_DEM/). At the bottom of the webpage, you will find a link to download a global scale 3 arc second MRR format terrain raster. It is about 47 GB.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please include the relevant information in your answer rather than links to answers.